# How do you obtain melons in Minecraft Xbox Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've played minecraft xbox edition for quite a while now, and I have not found ANY melons. I'm wondering if I have to find it in a chest, or if they spawn with the map?

Comment: well in the older versions of minecraft, the only way to get melons was to find the seeds in Dungeons or Abandoned Mines. I am going to assume that is how you will be able to get them.

Comment: Ok, but is that the only way, I don't feel like searching a whole buttload of cave systems to try and find a Dungeon. Try to make it easier for me =).

Comment: They are found in jungle biomes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to build a nether reactor with a nether reactor with diamonds and gold. Then activate it. You will have to build it in a non used area. You have to be quick to collect the things you can get but you will get a few things.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker is asking about the Xbox 360, not  Pocket.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them in a old mines.  There are miner's chests with melon seed, ores, and bread.

Answer (score 1):

The following top answer doesn't work, due to the fact the player's on Xbox. To find melons, go to Jungles. You can find melons near some of the Jungle trees. You can also find them as loot too in chests.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find melons in the same places as normal. However, if you want the block form in your inventory (as I don't remember if you can craft the block), you'd probably need Silk Touch, as it normally drops some of the item form of it.